# problem creating menu on android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a menu for my application and when it runs it just says sorry the application has stopped unexpectedly. I tried in another project and it worked, i'm trying with the simplest menu example and in one project works and the other doesn't. I don't show any code because it's the same everywhere i just would like to know why the application doesn't even start.

Comment: Could you please include a stacktrace from the failing application

Comment: Have you tried project -> clean?

Comment: Phil as amazing as it seems after cleaning it worked, what could you tell me about it? i mean why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Use logcat to see a stack trace of the failure... it should tell you the exception that caused the crash and the exact line in which file it occurred at.  If that doesn't help add you the stack trace to your posting.  Logcat is your best friend!

Comment: when it runs and evaluate this part of the code it crashes down btnScanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
But it's weird because in the other project i have the same code i showed 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                //le mando por parametro al intent los modos de scaneo que puede realizar la camara.
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","DATAMATRIX,QR_CODE,PRODUCT");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

Comment: But it's weird because i have the same code in the other project, the difference is when it works i have only 1 activity so every thing is there. When it fails i have some activitys and my menu it's not even in the activity of the code above and it can't run